# Is there a way in zAppDev (Mamba) to initialize an object upon creation like object initializers in C#?

Tags: zappdev

The following syntax doesn't pass the validation check.

```
var suggestionItem = new Domain.SuggestItem {Text: "", Description: "", Icon: ""};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mamba does not yet support object initializers. You should assign each property.

```
Domain.SuggestItem item;
item.Text = ""
```

etc

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** 
Just remember that in Mamba you don't need to worry about object initializations (no "new", no null checks, nothing). You just define your instance and then use it on the fly. Mamba will worry about its initialization, null values and the rest of the implementation details.